# Bloquear um elemento dentro da textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor

Preciso bloquear uma parte de um texto que está dentro `ckeditor` para que o usuário não delete e não altere aquela parte do texto, mas ele pode complementar o texto só não pode alterar aquela parte

```
<p>Essa parte nao pode ser alterada</p> <p>Essa aqui pode</p>
```

Poderia ser algum código `css` ou `javascript` que bloqueie essa alteração ? Ou teriam outras formas ?

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor não é `<textarea>`, é `contentEditable` (ou `docMode`), de qualquer forma creio que seja impossível impedir que o usuário interaja com o elemento, isto porque o controle fica todo sendo do usuário no `contentEditable`

O que recomendo é adicionar o elemento posteriormente, por exemplo no momento de enviar o form ou salvar os dados do form em algum lugar, supondo que use PHP, então bastaria inserir quando pegou os dados no servidor, algo como:

```
if (isset($_POST['dados'])) {
    $dados = $_POST['dados']; //Dados do textarea

    $dados .= '<div>Assinatura etc</div>'; //Adiciona uma assinatura
}
```

Isso é um exemplo apenas para entender, em caso de injetar em um lugar especifico você pode usar [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) para fazer poder trabalhar HTML com PHP e então usar uma das seguintes funções para selecionar o local exato que quer injetar uma tag especifica:

- `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagNameNS`
- `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`
- `DOMDocument::getElementById`

Ou usar a classe DomXpath para selecionar (que é bem mais avançada e pode simplifica o trabalho dependendo da complexidade do tipo de seleção):

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

E então com **uma** das seguintes funções:

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domnode.insertbefore.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domnode.appendchild.php

Depende muito da necessidade, entre essas duas.